# FlowDocument Repeating table header

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

How can I know if am at the end of a page and insert a break? I'm trying to print a wpf document with repeated header.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

There a good [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31834/FlowDocument-pagination-with-repeating-page-header) on that by [Bram Fokke](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/View.aspx?mid=5787472). It was written Dec 2008 so I'm not sure if it's still current or relevant. Hopefully it helps you.